# Amazon s3 bucket name warning from Fog gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, fog

I get this warning when all rails server, console setup.

[WARNING] fog: the specified s3 bucket name(hesaplabakalim-production/assets/new_opengraph) is not a valid dns name, which will negatively impact performance.

My fog configuration is like

```
connection = Fog::Storage.new({
:provider                 => 'AWS',
:aws_access_key_id        => "dummy",
:aws_secret_access_key    => "dummy"
})

$directory = connection.directories.create(
:key    => "dummy/assets/new_opengraph",
:public => true
)
```

I must actually create an bucket that's name is dummy and after that walk to assets/new_opengraph folder but i could not find it in fog documentation

Comment: hesaplabakalim-production is invalid name for bucket. Please don't use special characters

Answer (score 0):

I searched on fog gem's github page and i found this issue and solution.

> "on the empty folder, I have used zero byte files that we hide in the console that gives the semblance of creating empty folders. Cheap trick but works."

https://github.com/fog/fog/issues/1370